# Help implementing Lagrange inversion

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, warning-messages

I'm attempting to find the coefficients of generating functions using Lagrange inversion. I am finding the series coefficients with:

`p[n_] := Limit[D[((w - 1)/f[w])^n, {w, n - 1}], w -> 1]/n!`,

where `f` has one as a root (specific to what I am doing). This works fine with, for example, `p[1]` or `p[2]`; however, I am next trying to define the generating function in terms of this coefficients with:

`P[z_] := 1 + Sum[p[j]*z^j, {j, 1, Infinity}]`.

When I attempt to evaluate `P[z]`, I get the error *General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable.* I've learned that this is because it tries to evaluate the expression `p[j]*z^j` symbolically in terms of `j`, so what gets stored is $$\frac{\partial_{1,-1+j}1}{j!}$$ (Here, one is the limit of `f[w]` in my specific case.) That is, it takes the limit as $w\rightarrow 1$, but in doing so it just replaces `w` in the symbolic expression for the derivative.

Maybe I am misunderstanding the proper use of `Sum`, but my hope would be that it would not attempt to simplify/symbolically evaluate the expression until it has a definite value of `j` and then approximate the value of the infinite sum. Is there another function I'm unaware of that has this behavior?

Comment: `p[n]` is not evaluating sumbolically, and when `Limit` sees it it gets treated as something that can have 0 plugged in for `w` (because it is not seeing the expression as a numeric function).

Comment: Does `InverseSeries[]` solve your problem?